# Imagemagick does not show text but throws no errors either

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to generate some product badges for products in our system. Product badges are like [SO flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/295508.png), just a few composite images and some text. There is nothing wrong with the script as it runs fine on my development machine which runs Windows. However, on my production system (CentOS 5.1), it renders everything except the text.

I thought this was a font issue, but it doesn't work even if I copy the font file to the PHP file location nor did it work when I gave it a full path.

And it didn't work when I installed the Windows fonts for Linux as [described here](http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/).

I've typed `convert -list font` and it shows a list of fonts that Imagick knows about (parital list shown below)

```
  Font: Times-BoldItalic
    family: Times
    style: Italic
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 700
    glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n021024l.pfb
  Font: Times-Italic
    family: Times
    style: Italic
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 400
    glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n021023l.pfb
  Font: Times-Roman
    family: Times
    style: Normal
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 400
    glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/n021003l.pfb
```

I tried giving the absolute path listed here and it didn't work. I also tried just using the name and still nothing.

Basically the image shows up, but the text parts of it don't show up at all and no errors are thrown (see images below).

There's nothing wrong with the code and both Windows and CentOS are running close versions of Imagick (6.7.1-4 and 6.7.1-3). The only issue could be the font, I'm just putting normal TTF fonts up and testing, do I need some kind of special font to get it to work?

Working

[image: Working Image]

Broke

[image: Broken Image]

**EDIT** - Ignore the differences in the QR code and the ratings. This is due to the working badge and the non working badge being on two different servers.

**UPDATE 1** - I've run a simple test script and even that doesn't work. This is what I ran as a test : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-annotateimage.php The font just doesn't show up and no errors are thrown.

I've also copied a font from the CentOS system and tried it on the Windows box and it works fine. Fonts simply don't seem to work on CentOS.

I've also tried it without setting a font, I assume Imagick picks up a default font or something, and again works on Windows, but not on CentOS. I'm going to try this on a different *nix version to see what happens. Will update with findings.

**Update 3** : I've narrowed the issue down to a problem with the FreeType library I think. The forums say that FreeType needs to be installed for text to be displayed properly. And when I look at the config.log it tells me that there is an issue installing FreeType. Any heads up on this would be appreciated, meanwhile I'm going to re-install Freetype and run the installation again.

Comment: Is it significant at all that the three left-most stars are filled in in the **Working** image and they are all empty in the **Broke** image?

Comment: And bar code is different too ) But on the topic: have you tried some simple(very basic) script to check if fonts work in imagemagic(it is hard to debug A LOT of code)? If you did - please, post it here, I think you will get much more help.

Comment: Sorry about the image differences guys. The working one is from the local dev with local data and the non working one is from the staging server, hence the differences in data. I will setup a simpler test script and post it here. But my command line tests were unsuccessful. Will post those as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about CentOS but on my Ubuntu 9.10 with latest php5/php5-imagic specifying full path to font(or even placing font in the execution script's folder or relative path) works. Tested with default script from man http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-annotateimage.php , font setting function - ImagickDraw::setFont(). Tested font - some random free 3D font for windows.

Comment: @XzKto tried out the tests, no luck so far (see updates). Going to try this on a different *nix system to see whether it will work just to make sure it's a fault with my CentOS machine.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind - imagemagick uses a lot of external libraries, so maby some font library is not installed(broken dependencies etc.)? I think you should try to run command-line imagemagick tool "convert" with debugging turned to full and perform some font-related operation - it can give you some usefull information. Btw, have you tried to run that script with non-existent font?

Comment: @XzKto yeah, I think that's the case. I just posted an update to the question where it says FreeType is missing. Fake fonts throw an error so that seems ok. I'll try the command line now, maybe that will throw some more light on to it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just install Freetype. You actually have to install Freetype on your server, then recompile ImageMagick using the --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local option. Where /usr/local is the path to your Freetype install.

I believe it's normally /usr/local/bin

Give that a whirl and let us know what happens ;)

Comment: Yup, but the problem is that freetype was already installed but it was failing on the --with-freetype = on option. I think I probably need to define the dir of where it's installed as well. I'll try specifying the directory as you say, maybe that will help. Thanks!

Comment: I double checked and the command should be used: --with-freetype-dir=/path/to/freetype

Comment: Sorry I took so long to get back, I just noticed that the script works now! Our sysadmin went through several cycles of installs, removals and recompiles. At any rate, up and working. Thanks!